# Hibernate search too few results

Tags: java, lucene, hibernate-search

I have a relation: `Document2 ->* DocVersion` meaning document has multiple versions, to be clear.

Now I want to get all `DocVersion`s based on unique `Document2`s field.

Entities:

```
@Indexed
@Entity
public class DocVersion implements Serializable {

    ...
    @Id
    @Column(name = "version_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private long id;
    ...

    @IndexedEmbedded
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "doc_uuid")
    private Document2 document2;

    @Field
    private String versionVed;

    private String versionOKM;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        DocVersion version = (DocVersion) o;
        return id == version.id &&
            Objects.equals(versionVed, version.versionVed) &&
            Objects.equals(versionOKM, version.versionOKM);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        return Objects.hash(id, versionVed, versionOKM);
    }
}


@Indexed
@Entity
public class Document2 implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "doc_uuid")
    private long id;

    @Field
    @Analyzer(impl = WhitespaceAnalyzer.class)
    @Column(name = "uuid")
    private String UUID;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Document2 document2 = (Document2) o;
        return Objects.equals(UUID, document2.UUID);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        return Objects.hash(UUID);
    }

}
```

this is how I construct query:

```
        QueryBuilder b = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory()
                .buildQueryBuilder()
                .forEntity(DocVersion.class)
                .get();

        BooleanQuery.Builder builder = new BooleanQuery.Builder();

builder.add(b.simpleQueryString().onField("document2.UUID").matching(val)
                        .createQuery(), MUST);

List<DocVersion> results = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(builder.build(), DocVersion.class).getResultList();
```

and I get one result. I consider this fault, because doc's UUID I'm querying has more (two) `DocVersion`s on it. Surely DBs returns two rows.
So why am I getting only one with Lucene? How to fix this?

hibernate-search: 5.9.3.Final

Comment: Check if you have a consistent equals() and hashCode() method in your classes.

Comment: @minus yes, actually DocVersions are stored in Document2 as set and as I get only one docVersion back, I can go through it to the document and there are two of them in the Set<>. So there would be only one if it would be caused by badly implemented hashCode&equals, I guess

Answer (score 0):

Check that:

1. You correctly set `DocVersion.document2` whenever you persist a `DocVersion`. It's a common mistake to forget to set both sides of a bidirectional association (i.e. maybe you just called something like `document2.getVersions().add(version)`, but not `version.setDocument2(document2)`).
2. You reindexed since you last changed your Hibernate Search mapping. You can use the [mass indexer](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.9/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-batchindex-massindexer) if you want to reindex from an already populated database.

Also, this is a bad idea that could lead to unexpected behavior:

```
@Field
@Analyzer(impl = WhitespaceAnalyzer.class)
@Column(name = "uuid")
private String UUID;
```

An UUID field is not a good candidate for full-text Search, since you probably want exact matches. Just disable analysis:

```
@Field(analyze = Analyze.NO)
@Column(name = "uuid")
private String UUID;
```

Comment: I am setting it bi-directionally, besides of this lucene thing it works well... and as I mention in the comment above, I can see the set of two docVersions in document2 field of the returned docVersion instance. but I need to get both from lucene.
yes, Analyze.NO is probably better way to go

Comment: and at this stage,I'm just starting with Lucene, so I run app fresh and index entities on the startup. not persisting entities during the run, it's loaded from db as is..two of docVersions

Comment: @greengold How do you index the entities exactly? Did you check your logs, in case some background indexing work failed?

Comment: FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager); ...nothing fancy. you know, it's not that I'm not getting data, but I should get two of that entites. each have slightly different values in some fields but references the same document2 by it's uuid prop.

Comment: Yes, I understand the problem. I'm asking for more information so I can find out where the problem comes from. Depending on how you index your entities, it's totally possible that a misplaced `session.clear()` would prevent some (and only some) of the entities from being indexed. If you don't want to give more information, I'm afraid I won't be able to help you...

Comment: you see all I have regarding hibernate-sesarch. not clearing session at all
but I found it!

Answer (score 0):

through all replies were valid and worth consider for someone going around with this kind of problem, for me what caused this "misbehave" was bad data in the database on one of the indexed leaves with null value that hibernate-search didn't grasp therefore I was missing results.